# Use TextFormatMinibatchSource to import double dataypes

Tags: c#, cntk

is it possible to use the CNTK TextFormatMinibatchSource with datatype Double? Can I import the training data as double values instead of floats?

Thanks

Comment: Wondering myself, have been unable to find a way yet

Comment: Since not much response here I opened an issue at GitHub for this. 'MinibatchSource always returns float datatype so model cannot use double as datatype #2623'